# Reaching link local IP addresses from windows container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-container

I have Windows 2019 VM instance on Google Compute Engine.  I am trying to run docker container which needs to be able to reach GCE Metadata server (169.254.169.254 - link local IP).  I am able to reach GCE Metadata server from the host just fine, but when I run docker container which uses default nat network it can't reach GCE Metadata server.   I know this works just fine on Linux, but I can't seem to get it working on Windows.

Here is what I already tried:

1. Created Win 2019 GCE VM instance.
2. Start docker container (it can reach external endpoints and local IP addresses, but not local link ip address like 169.254.169.254):

```
docker run -ti mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 powershell

PS C:\> nslookup metadata.google.internal
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.19.32.1

*** UnKnown can't find metadata.google.internal: Server failed
PS C:\> ping 169.254.169.254

Pinging 169.254.169.254 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.19.42.234: Destination host unreachable.
```

3. Tried to create l2bridge network without outbound NAT enabled. DNS is working and I can reach metadata.google.internal (169.254.169.254), but can't reach external or internal IP addresses.

```
docker network create -d "l2bridge" --subnet 10.128.0.0/20 --gateway 10.128.0.1 -o com.docker.network.windowsshim.dnsservers="10.128.0.1" l2bridge
```

4. Tried to create l2bridge network with outbound NAT configured. No internet connection whatsoever!

```
docker network create -d "l2bridge" --subnet 10.128.0.0/20 --gateway 10.128.0.1 -o com.docker.network.windowsshim.dnsservers="10.128.0.1" -o com.docker.network.windowsshim.enable_outboundnat=true -o com.docker.network.windowsshim.outboundnat_exceptions=10.128.0.0/20,169.254.0.0/16 l2bridge_outnat
```

How do I get windows container running on GCE instance that has functional network and can reach GCE Metadata server?

Comment: You need to add a route inside the Windows container. This link to AWS documentation will work in Google Cloud Windows containers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/windows_task_IAM_roles.html